# directive: controller is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

very new to angular; try to understand why this directive doesn't work. Please point me to the directions on the what concepts to learn.

The directive **was working** when I had write out **the template as a string**, but it is very ugly and i want to put them in a separate html file.

in index.html

```
<div message-modal trigger="trigger_message_modal"></div>
```

**The error message**: `$scope.trigger_message_modal is not a function`

the NOT working directives.js

```
app.module.directive('messageModal', function ($compile) {
  return {
        scope: {
            trigger: "=trigger"
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$timeout', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {

                $scope.trigger = function(title, message, modal_class, color, auto_hide){
                    $scope.message = message;
                    $scope.modal_class = modal_class;
                    $scope.color = color;
                    $scope.title = title;

                    $('#messageWell').modal('show');

                    if(auto_hide == true){
                        $timeout(function(){
                            $('#messageWell').modal('hide');
                        }, 1000)   
                    }
                };
        }],
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl :"well.html"                        
    };
});
```

Comment: Where is `$scope.trigger_message_modal` triggered from? Could it be a timing issue with the function getting triggered before the directive controller is instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

The directive is restricted to E which means the directive should be used as an element, 
`<message-modal trigger="trigger_message_modal"> </message-modal>`. Only then the `trigger` attribute can be used in the directive using the directive's scope.
If you require the `message-modal` to be used as an attribute, then change the restrict to `A` but you will not be able to access `trigger` as a scope variable and need to be accessed using the parent element's `$attrs`.

Comment: Why you can't access `trigger` while using restrict `A`?

Comment: `trigger` cannot be accessed in its scope. Can only be accessed from the parent attribute. Have edited my answer to make it clear.

Comment: I tried using both and they pretty much worked the same [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sutedunoxo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @rraman, I am confused too. I changed  the restrict to A and used $attrs instead of $scope. It still doesn't work